# What's your recommended Service Manager for Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service

I am setting up a Windows Server which will have some non-service apps running all the time. Since I don't want to login everytime just to start the apps, I want to use a *Service Manager*.

Microsoft's `srvany` is freely available. But do you know of other **freeware** (preferably, also **Open Source**) service managers?

I also found this: [**"NSSM - Non-Sucking Service Manager"**](https://iain.cx/src/nssm/) ... any experience in using it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it is missing some mandatory functionality you need, I'd suggest using the built-in `sc` command. You can create your own services within Windows without using third-party utilities.

Edit: Here's a Technet article, courtesy of squillman: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: Can `sc` make a non-service app into a service?

Comment: @pepoluan Yes, see this Technet article. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192